# Show that faithful action of groups of order $128$ on sets of order $8$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G_1, G_2$ both be groups of order $128$, $X_1, X_2$ be sets of order $8$. $G_i$ acts on $X_i$ faithfully. Show that there exists an isomorphism $f: G_1 \cong G_2$ and a bijection $p：X_1 \cong X_2$ such that $p(gx) = f(g)p(x)$.

No idea what is involved in this problem. Maybe I should start with that $G_i$'s are both embedded into $S_8$. $8! = 2^7 \times 7 \times 3^2$. So $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both sylow-2 subgroups of $S_8$. Then there exists $h \in S_8$ such that $hG_1h^{-1} = G_2$. Now I have my group isomorphism. Then I want $p$ to satisfy: $p(gx) = hgh^{-1}p(x)$. How should I continue？

Let me try to do this using the comment:

First pick a bijection $p: X_1 \to X_2$, define an action of $G_2$ on $X_1$ by $g \times x = p^{-1}g p(x)$. Then by the comment we know that $h g_1 x = h g_1 h^{-1} \times h x =p^{-1} hgh^{-1}p(hx)$ and $p(gx)= hgx$. Then $phg_1x = hgh^{-1}p(hx)$. So it suffices to define $\bar p = p\circ h$.

Comment: At the moment your equation $hG_1h^{-1} = G_2$ does no make much sense because $G_1$  and $G_2$ are not given as a subgroups of $S_8$. The easiest case is when $X_1 = X_2$, and $G \le {\rm Sym}(X_1)$. Then you can just take $p=h$. In general you need to start with a bijection $X_1 to X_2$, which effectively enables you to assume that $X_1=X_2$, and injective hommmorphisms from $G1$ and $G_2$ to ${\rm Sym}(X_1)$ and ${\rm Sym}(X_2)$, and then $p$ will be some composite of $h$ with these maps.

Comment: Well if I can do it for 2-sylow subgroups of $G$ then I can do it for groups of order $128$. Do you mean that I should start with any given bijection between $X_1$ and $X_2$? How should I produce $f$ then?